# How do i tell the check_box method to NOT add a hidden check_box for the 'unchecked' value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm using rails 2.3.4, which, when you call .check_box on the 'f' object in a form_for, makes a visible checkbox input for the 'checked' value, and a hidden checkbox input for the 'unchecked' value: http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M002434&name=check_box

The problem with this is that i have a validates_acceptance_of validation on the check_box, and if it's not checked, i'm getting a field_with_errors div wrapped around the visible checkbox AND the hidden checkbox, so that the error message appears twice.

In this instance i don't want a value passed through in the 'unchecked' case, so i don't want rails to add the hidden checkbox - this (switching off the hidden checkbox) would solve my problem.  I can't figure out how to tell it to not add the hidden checkbox though.  Can anyone tell me?

I know that i could get round this by making a check_box_tag, which doesn't add the hidden 'unchecked' case checkbox, but then i don't get field_with_errors stuff wrapped around the checkbox if it's not checked.  Dispensing with the hidden field seems like the cleanest solution.

Thanks - max

Comment: Hey Max, any chance you could update the correct answer selection? There is now a built in override argument for this, so the selected correct answer no longer is.

Comment: @RedBassett my question was about 2.3.4 so I don't want to change the correct answer to something that only applies to a later version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `<%= check_box_tag "your_model[your_field]" %>`

`f.check_box` always gives you a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's what i ended up doing while i waited to see if there was a nicer solution.  It's a pain though as like i say you have to do the fieldWithErrors stuff manually.

Comment: or defining your own form builder? though defining a form builder maybe more difficult than using `check_box_tag` with error msg, it is actually worth to do it.

Comment: Yeah, a custom form builder is the way to go i suppose.  I've done it before and it seems like a hassle but still probably saves you time as you then have total control.

Comment: not always you can write check_box("puppy", "commands", {:multiple => true}, "sit", nil)

Answer (score 45):

In Rails 4 you can use `include_hidden: false`

example `f.check_box :some_field, include_hidden: false`

Comment: As it is, this isn't a useful answer. Maybe you should expand your answer to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Added example of usage

Answer (score 6):

Since Rails 3.2, the hidden field will not be shown if the `unchecked_value` argument evaluates to `false`.

Example: `f.check_box :your_field, {}, checked_value, false`

See the Rails source: [3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1100), 
[4.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/check_box.rb#L59)

Answer (score 1):

So this is interesting. check_box takes four arguments as the method definition shows:

```
  def check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
    Tags::CheckBox.new(object_name, method, self, checked_value, unchecked_value, options).render
  end
```

The checked value and unchecked value must be the third and fourth argument. By setting an unchecked_value that evaluates to a truthy value, then the hidden input will appear.

My initial goal was to have a visible checkbox with a value of true, and a hidden checkbox with a value of false. So I tried doing this:

```
<%= f.check_box :share, { }, true, false %>
```

However, because I actually passed in a boolean value for unchecked value, it made the hidden field not appear at all! I tracked it down to this line of code in the Rails source:

```
    def hidden_field_for_checkbox(options)
      @unchecked_value ? tag("input", options.slice("name", "disabled", "form").merge!("type" => "hidden", "value" => @unchecked_value)) : "".html_safe
    end
```

If @unchecked_value evaluates to false or nil, then no hidden input field would display. Now if you want to send true and false values rather than '1' or '0' using check_box helper, then you will need to wrap the booleans in strings:

```
 <%= f.check_box :share, { }, 'true', 'false' %>
```

But if that's the case, you matters well just use the defaults of `'1'` and `'0'` for boolean values and let Rails handle it.

Rails stores booleans as TinyInt, at least for the MySQL database. Consequently, that '1' will get stored in the database as 1 and will be considered a true value.